# Pandas update field value with the output of another condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, mask

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

What I want to achieve is, if id1 is not equal to id2, I want to update the y values (in `name` column) with x value (x is when id1 equals to id2).

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
                     'id2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                     'name': ['x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x']})
```

what I did is this:

```
test.loc[test['id1'] != test['id2'], 'name'] = test[test['id1'] == test['id2']]['name'].tolist()[0]
```

It works well, but I don't like the way I solved it (because of this `.tolist()[0]`). I feel there is another more correct solution.

Edit:

Sometimes we don't have `id1==id2` in this Dataframe, so my solution will produce an error, because there no elements in `test[test['id1'] == test['id2']]['name'].tolist()[0]`.

Comment: It seems that you want to have `x` everywhere then: where `id1` equals `id2` and when `id1` is *not* equal to `id2`. Is this correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: Your left condition does not return the same number of elements from your right condition. That's why you use `.tolist()[0]` to have only one scalar value.

Comment: @sheldon yes! bear in mind that sometimes we don't have `id1==id2` in this dataframe, so my solution will produce an error. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: @Corralien exactly. Is this way of solving it ok? I just edited the post; I added a comment.

Comment: And if you have multiple id1 == id2 for different names, what do you want to do?

Comment: @Corralien, no I won't have this. id1==id2 always have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use `where` then `ffill / bfill` and `fillna` to leave your dataframe untouched if no rows match `id1 == id2`:

```
test['name'] = (test['name'].where(test['id2'] == test['id1'])
                            .ffill().bfill().fillna(test['name']))
```

Output:

```
>>> test
   id1  id2 name
0    1    1    x
1    1    1    x
2    1    1    x
3    2    1    x
4    2    1    x
5    1    1    x
```